# Case Classes and Pattern Matching on List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

What I would like to do is simplify this expression

**Opt(Opt**(ExpList(List(**Opt(Opt**(Var("optional")))))))

to get something like that

**Opt**(ExpList(List(**Opt**(Var("optional")))))

---

What would match expression look like in order to simplify all expressions inside the list.

What are best-practises for those kind of tasks?

The code snippet I tried is this:

```
object CaseClassPatternMatching extends App {
  abstract class Expr
  case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
  case class Opt(expr: Expr) extends Expr
  case class ExpList(listExp: List[Expr]) extends Expr

  def joinOpt(feature: Expr): Expr = feature match {
    case Opt(Opt(f)) => joinOpt(Opt(f))    // Opt(Opt("test")) --> Opt("test")
    // case ExpList(list) => ????          // What to do there?
    case _ => feature
  }

  val expr1: Expr = joinOpt(Opt(Opt(Opt(Var("optional")))))
  println(Opt(Var("optional"))) 
  // Output: Opt(Var(optional))  --> That one is OK...

  val expr2: Expr = joinOpt(Opt(Opt(ExpList(List(Opt(Opt(Var("optional"))))))))
  println(expr2)
  // Output: Opt(ExpList(List(Opt(Opt(Var(optional))))))  --> Not OK...
  // How to simplify expressions inside list?
}
```

---

### [EDIT]

For those of you who are interested, similar topic:

[Scala case classes, pattern matching and varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9220167/617996)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need four cases:

```
def joinOpt(feature: Expr): Expr = feature match {
                         // remove extra Opt 
                         // (you can use @ to avoid recreating Opt)
  case Opt(opt @ Opt(_)) => joinOpt(opt) 
                         // preserve single Opt
  case Opt(expr)         => Opt(joinOpt(expr)) 
                         // apply function to all elements in inner list
  case ExpList(list)     => ExpList(list map joinOpt) 
  case _ => feature
}
```

Comment: It's annoying to have missed a case... :-) If I had enumerated all cases instead of relying on a default, the compiler would have warned me. Let that serve as a lesson to me. :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, `abstract class Expr` should be sealed to get warnings... Am I right?

Comment: @PrimosK Yes, but you won't get warnings if you use a default -- a default will always catch all cases. If you avoid using default cases, however, the compiler will tell you if you missed something. Mostly -- the current implementation has some bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd write `joinOpt` like this:

```
def joinOpt(feature: Expr): Expr = feature match {
  case Opt(Opt(f))   => joinOpt(Opt(f))    // Opt(Opt("test")) --> Opt("test")
  case ExpList(list) => ExpList(list map joinOpt)
  case other         => other
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work... <console>:14: Error: star patterns must correspond with varargs parameters... This is the message I get...

Comment: @PrimosK Oh, sorry, I thought this was a vargarg/unapplySeq. Corrected.

Comment: Hmm.. I still get Opt(ExpList(List(Opt(Opt(Var(optional))))))... What exactly ExpList(list map joinOpt) do?

Comment: It recursively joins `Opt`s of `Opt`s that might be contained in list of expressions. So `List(Opt(f), Opt(Opt(g)), ExpList(List(Opt(Opt(h)))))` would become `List(Opt(f), Opt(g), ExpList(List(Opt(h)))`.