# Case classes, pattern matching and varargs

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Let's say I have such class hierarchy:

```
abstract class Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
case class ExpList(listExp: List[Expr]) extends Expr
```

Would it be better to define constructor of `ExpList` like this:

```
case class ExpList(listExp: Expr*) extends Expr
```

I would like to know, what are drawbacks/benefits of each definitions regards pattern matching?

Comment: I would like to do few normalizations over expressions... For example, one of the normalization rules is: Nested lists are ﬂattened....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have both constructors:

```
case class ExpList(listExp: List[Expr]) extends Expr
object ExpList {
  def apply(listExp: Expr*) = new ExpList(listExp.toList)
}

//now you can do
ExpList(List(Var("foo"), Var("bar")))
//or
ExpList(Var("foo"), Var("bar"))
```

Variadic arguments are converted to a `mutable.WrappedArray`, so to keep in line with the convention of case classes being immutable, you should use a list as the actual value.

Comment: Actually, the OP should use an immutable sequence - but I believe that Lists are often misused, as they are not the universal sequence type.
I'd rather accept `Seq` as `ExpList`'s parameter, and define `ExpList.apply` to return `new ExpList(Seq(listExp: _*))`.

Comment: @Blaisorblade You can do `listExp.toSeq`

Comment: @dhg: won't give the desired result. `WrappedArray[T] <: Seq[T]`, therefore `listExp.toSeq` will just upcast `listExp`. Upcasting `listExp` is possible, but will not prevent somebody downcasting it again and modifying it. If you assume nobody doing this, you needn't do anything explicitly, once you change `ExpList` to be declared as `case class ExpList(listExp: Seq[Expr]) extends Expr`, which you should do anyway IMHO.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I see now.  I assumed `toSeq` would return an `immutable.Seq` in the same way that `toMap` returns an `immutable.Map` and `toSet` returns an `'immutable.Set`, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can one of you provide the content of the above comments as an answer with slightly more explanation involved? TY

Comment: @PrimosK: there were some problems with that solution, but I can still answer the original question another way.

Comment: @dhg: you're right, that's inconsistent. The general rule seems to be that the types allow returning the receiver of the method call if appropriate.

Comment: @PrimosK: I wrote down a complete answer, and I highlighted examples of pattern-matching as per your question.

Answer (score 19):

Let's answer the different questions involved here. I would indeed recommend this syntax:

```
case class ExpList(listExp: Expr*) extends Expr
```

But the answer depends on your coding example. So let's see how to use varargs in pattern matching, when to use `List`, and the problem with WrappedArray.
A small remark: the inconsistency between `Expr` and `ExpList` (with or without 'r'?) is problematic when typing and trying to remember which is which - stick to one convention, `Exp` is clear enough and often used.

### Varargs and pattern matching

Let us first consider this declaration:

```
abstract class Expr
case class ExpList(listExp: Expr*) extends Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
```

And this code example:

```
val v = Var("a")
val result = for (i <- Seq(ExpList(v), ExpList(v, v), ExpList(v, v, v))) yield (i match {
  case ExpList(a) => "Length 1 (%s)" format a
  case ExpList(a, b, c, d @ _*) => "Length >= 3 (%s, %s, %s, %s...)" format (a, b, c, d)
  case ExpList(args @ _*) => "Any length: " + args
})
result foreach println
```

produces:

```
Length 1 (Var(a))
Any length: WrappedArray(Var(a), Var(a))
Length >= 3 (Var(a), Var(a), Var(a), WrappedArray()...)
```

What I use here:
`ExpList(a, b)` matches a ExpList with two children; `ExpList(a)` matches a ExpList with one child.
`_*` is a pattern which matches sequences of values of type `A` which can be arbitrarily long (including 0).
I also use pattern binders, `identifier @ pattern`, which allow to bind an object while also further destructuring it with another pattern; they work with any pattern, not just `_*`.

When using `identifier @ _*`, `identifier` is bound to type `Seq[A]`.

All these constructs also apply to `Seq`; but if we do use `Seq` in the declaration, like this:

```
case class ExpList(listExp: Seq[Expr]) extends Expr
```

the same case clauses change from (for instance) `case ExpList(a, b, c, d @ _*) =>` to `case ExpList(Seq(a, b, c, d @ _*)) =>`. So more syntactic clutter.

Syntactically speaking, the only thing which is 'harder' with `Expr*` is writing the following function, which constructs a ExpList from an expression list:

```
def f(x: Seq[Expr]) = ExpList(x: _*)
```

Note the use (again) of `_*` here.

### The `List` class

`List` is convenient to use when you pattern match on the list head constructor, as in `xs match { case head :: tail => ... case Nil => }`. However, usually this code can be expressed more compactly using folds, and if you are not writing code in this style, you needn't use `List`. Especially in an interface, it is often good practice to require only what your code is going to need.

### Mutability

What we discussed above concerned immutability. Instances of case classes should be immutable. Now, when using `Expr*`, the parameter of the case class has in fact type `collection.Seq[Expr]`, and this type contains mutable instances - in fact, ExprList will receive an instance of the subclass `WrappedArray`, which is mutable. Note that `collection.Seq` is a superclass of both `collection.mutable.Seq` and `collection.immutable.Seq`, and the latter is aliased to `Seq` by default.

One cannot mutate such a value without downcasting it, but it is still possible for somebody to do it (I don't know for what reason).

If you want to prevent your client from doing it, you need to convert the value you receive to an immutable sequence - but you cannot do it when declaring ExpList with `case class ExpList(listExp: Expr*) extends Expr`.

You need instead to use another constructor.
To do the conversion in the other code, since `toSeq` returns the original sequence, you must call `Seq`'s constructor with the content of the list as variadic arguments. Hence, you use the syntax I showed above, `Seq(listExpr: _*)`.
Presently that does not matter so much since `Seq`'s default implementation is `List`, but that might change in the future (maybe to something faster, who knows?).

### Erasure problems

One cannot declare two overloads of the same method, one taking `T*` and one taking `Seq[T]`, because in the output class they would become the same. A little trick to make the m look different and have two constructors can be used:

```
case class ExpList(listExp: Seq[Expr]) extends Expr
object ExpList {
 def apply(listExp: Expr*)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = new ExpList(Seq(listExp: _*))
}
```

Here I also convert the array to an immutable sequence, as above. Pattern matching is done, unfortunately, as in the example above where the case class accepts `Seq[Expr]` instead of `Expr*`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a comment to Dan's solution: If you have this inside a function it does, due to the bug in Scala not work https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3772. You get something like:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
    def g(){
        class Expr {}
        case class ExpList(listExp: List[Expr]) extends Expr
        object ExpList {
          def apply(listExp: Expr*) = new ExpList(listExp.toList)
        }
    }
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:10: error: ExpList is already defined as (compiler-generated) case cla
ss companion object ExpList
                    object ExpList {
                           ^
```

For now the workaround is simply to put the object first.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
    def g(){
        class Expr {}
        object ExpList {
          def apply(listExp: Expr*) = new ExpList(listExp.toList)
        }
        case class ExpList(listExp: List[Expr]) extends Expr
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
g: ()Unit
```

I hope that will prevent people from stumbling over this bug as I did.