# @_* extractor not compiling in Scala

Tags: scala

I suppose `@_*` matches variable argument list. I am trying to use it as following but the code isn't compiling.

```
val l= List(1,2,3,4,5)
l match {
    case (first +: second +: rest@_*) => println("atleast 2 elements in the list")
}
```

Comment: In your example, just removing the `@_*` would make it work. You can find an good explanation on its use here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229677/7579547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

Have your `List()` match a `List()`:

```
case List(first, second, rest@_*) => . . .
```

Or match your `List()` against a sequence of connected elements:

```
case first +: second +: rest => . . .
```

Either way, the identifiers `first` and `second` will be populated the 1st and 2nd values from the list, and `rest` will contain whatever remains.

Comment: Thanks. Is it because a List is created either using List(...) or (a +:(b +: Nil)) syntax?

Comment: @ManuChadha; Yes, more or less. If `case` is followed by a pattern that could build a `List()` then the `unapplySeq()` method of the `List` companion object will be called to complete the pattern match.